# create link to a serve a website in nginx

Tags: server, nginx

I am wondering if it is possible to create link to serve a website ?

I know that we can use :

```
...    
server_name 123.123.123.123;
...
root /var/www/test;
```

but is it possible to use something like:

```
server_name 123.123.123.123/test;
...
root /var/www/test;
```

Use a link to serve certain directory

Answer (score 1):

Just add them to your config as follows for each directory you want to serve

```
location /test {
    root /var/www/test;
}
```